# PHP not opening SQLite3 database

Tags: php, nginx, sqlite

I'm running a small web server on my raspberry pi using nginx, php5, and sqlite3. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to insert some data into my database, it just stops at `sqlite_open()`. No errors, it just stops.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>halp</title>
<style>
* {font-family:verdana;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><h2>Log in</h2></p>
<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td><td><input type="checkbox" value="r" name="r"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['r']) || isset($_POST['user'])){
$reg = $_POST['r'];
if($reg == 'r'){
//      echo $reg, "<br>";
        echo "Registering... <br>";
        $user = md5($_POST['user']);
        $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
//      echo "user and pass <br>";
//      echo "user: ", $user, " pass: ", $pass, "<br>";
        try{
//              echo "inside try <br>";
                $db = sqlite_open('testdb', 0666, $error);    //stops here
                echo "error: ", $error->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "error: ", $e->getMessage();
        }
//      echo "sqlite_open <br>";
        if(!$db) { die($error); }
        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$user', '$pass')";
        $registered = sqlite_query($db, $query);
//      echo "sqlite_exec";
        if($registered){
                echo "New user registered.<br>";
//              echo $user."        ";
//              echo $pass;
        } else { die($error); }
        sqlite_close($db);
}
else{
        $user = md5($_POST['user']);
        $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
//      print $user."\n";
//      print $pass."\n";
        $db = new SQLite3('testdb');
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$pass';");
        if(!$results){ echo 'Database error'; }
        else {
                $resultArray = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
                if($resultArray[0] == $user && $resultArray[1] == $pass){
                        echo 'Password and username match found!';
                }
                else{
                        echo 'Password and username do not match.';
                }
        }
}
}
?>
<br>
<a href="index.html">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Once it gets to `sqlite_open()` it stops. As you can see, there is a link to `index.html` at the bottom of the code, but when I run this file, it does not display. The `echo`s that I have commented out tell me that I only get as far as the try statement.

I have tried several things to resolve this:

- Creating a database using `sqlite3` in command line
- Messing with nginx & php configs

  - Specifically, using my own sites-enabled
  - Changing the value of `sqlite.assoc_case` in `php.ini`. Frustratingly, there is a link to a page on php.net that does not exist.
- Because `sqlite_open()` creates a database if it is not found, I used that to create `testdb`
- `chmod a+rwx testdb`
- `chmod a+rwx /var/www/html`
- Adding myself to `www-data` group
- `chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html`
- Different browsers

  - IE hates it
- Rebooting even

This wouldn't be so rage inducing if I *at least had an error message.* gah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sqlite_open()* only supports sqlite2. Use PDO to access sqlite3 databases:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:testdb');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES(':user', ':pass')");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just an issue of finding the docs confusing, then. On the page for `sqlite_open()`, someone had pointed out that it was only for sqlite2, but they were totally buried by downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that PHP has a dedicated package for SQLite3 very cleverly named 'SQLite3'. Check out the PHP manual entry.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Here's some code snippets that should help.

```
$db = new SQLite3.php('testdb');
$results = $db->query($query);
while($row = $results->fetchArray()){
    var_dump($row);echo "<br/>";
}
$db->close();
```